# Android TextView

Tags: android, textview, drawable

I have an example in android that I am trying to run.
There were 2 ways to do it..

```
// Get a drawable 
ColorDrawble redDrawable = (ColorDrawable).getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle); 

//Set it as a background to a text view 
textView.setBackground(redDrawable);
```

When I put this in the Eclipse IDE I get an error ColorDrawble cannot be resolved to a type
I have the textview in the main XML

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
    <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:id="@+id/texter"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
          android:text="this string"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

---

and the resources in the strings xml file

```
<resources>
    <string name="hello">Hello World, ResourceTesterActivity!</string>
    <string name="app_name">ResourceTester</string>
     <drawable name="red_rectangle" >#f00</drawable> 
    <drawable name="blue_rectangle">#0000ff</drawable> 
    <drawable name="green_rectangle" >#f0f0</drawable>
</resources>
```

**

Comment: Why do you store drawable resources inside strings.xml?

Comment: it's from an adndroid example.. from PRO android 2 http://www.amazon.com/Pro-Android-Sayed-Y-Hashimi/dp/1430226595

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply use a drawable like this :

```
// Get a drawable 
Drawable redDrawable = YourActivity.this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle); 

//Set it as a background to a text view 
textView.setBackgroundDrawable(redDrawable);//i've changed setBackground with setBackgroundDrawable.
```

or you can directly use :

```
textView.setBackgroundResources(R.drawable.red_rectangle);
```

**NOTE :** clean and rebuild your project  , and run it to test 
and for the drawable, you dont need to declare it in strings.xml , just add your drawable on the folder drawables , and it will work

Comment: Thank-you for your replt. think i need to make the object textView? i am gettign an error textView cannot be resolved

Comment: make sure that your layout contains a textView, and rebuild your project : go to menu PROJECT ==> CLEAN ==> Choose your project ==> And press OK .

Comment: if i change the code to this..

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView1);
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_rectangle);

i get error on the emulator Sorry! ResouceTester has stopped unexpectedly

Comment: change the method `setBackgroundResource(int res)` with `setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle);`

Comment: thanks for your reply..
i have changed it to : 

 TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView1);
            tv.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle)‌​;

but getting syntax error, missing ; sorry for the trouble but i am new at java/android

Comment: hi, already tried that once i add a ')' , i get a- syntax error - insert ';' to complete statement.

Comment: plz paste your code and i will figure it out, u forgot ; somewhere in your code , or an }; paste your new code in your question after editing it

Comment: i tried changing the code above, was unalbe to do it. Where can i paste it. Seems to do an edit you need privileges and i don't have those.

Comment: thank you for all your help, your code gave me another idea and it worked.
  Resources res = getResources();
  Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle);
  TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView1);
tv.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle)‌​);
        tv.setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);

Answer (score 0):

It should be:

```
ColorDrawble redDrawable = (ColorDrawable) 
          getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.red_rectangle);
```

You don't need the dot (perhaps it's a typo).

Then press Ctrl+Shift+O (Organize Imports) to import ColorDrawble class.

Comment: thanks for your reply. I am gettign 2 errors. 1. ColorDrawable cannot be resolved to a type, 2. textView cannot be resolved

Comment: Yes you are right does not need a dot, still getting a problem with the textView. Do i have to declare a new object like TextView textview= new Textview(textView); ??

Comment: if i change the code to this..

TextView tv = (TextView)findViewById (R.id.textView1);
tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.red_rectangle);

i get error on the emulator Sorry! ResouceTester has stopped unexpectedly